# PHP and ClamAV socket programming

Tags: php, sockets, antivirus, clam

I'm really new to ClamAV and PHP socket programming.

And need to create a socket file that the ClamAV daemon will listen on.

I really don't know how to connect to ClamAV at all or where to begin any help will be great.